# AJAX Response To Change DIV Height Percentage

Tags: jquery, ajax

I had logic that I have been using for the past 2 years without any problems. All of the sudden it seems that it won't update when called (every 10 seconds).

Below is the receiver of the AJAX call. Typical values returned include "10%", "45%", "80%" up to and over 100%. I'm trying to update the height to the returned percentage and update a div with some text. The text updates properly but the height param doesn't move.

```
 xmlhttper.onreadystatechange=function() {
   if (xmlhttper.readyState==4 && xmlhttper.status==200) {
      var x = xmlhttper.responseText;
      document.getElementById("percentfill").innerHTML = x;
      $('#percentfill').animate({ 
          height: x
      }, 1500 );
   }
 }
```

In Chrome I can pass $("#percentfill").animate({height:"50%"},1500); and it works properly. Any ideas why it might stop working?

Comment: -snip- edit: correction.  It's already displaying the value.  White space might be an issue.  Is the javascript console throwing any errors?

Comment: Good question. No errors from console. I'll try the white space.

Comment: White space didn't change it. Using jQuery 1.5.0 if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was including config files (php) and there was a white space in the external config file.